# Best way to match a string to an array of possible similar strings?

Tags: php, string-matching, strpos

Every day I get several excel files from different companies with product information and the only way to match the products to my own database is via the product name. These companies are not organized, the product names are typed by hand and may vary in the same excel file.

What is the best way to find the closest match to my own product list? Sometimes company A might call a product "Toy car 100" where I don't care about which number it is, I simply call this "Toy car". However sometimes they may call it something different like "Provision for toy that is a car" and I then need to match that to my "Toy car" product.

**What is the best way to do this matching of strings, basically I want to match strings that are the most similar.**

My current implementation involves writing many if statements like this, creating new if statements when a variation can not be matched correctly.

```
foreach ($prodset as $p) {
    if (strpos(strtolower($dd['offer_name']), strtolower($p['prod_info'])) !== false && $p['active'] == 1) {
        $dd['product_id'] = $p['prod_id'];
        $result = $dd;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [similar_text](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) function, which calculates the similarity between two strings.

```
<?php

$base = 'Toy car';

$variations = array(
    'Provision for toy that is a car',
    'Toy that looks like a car',
    'Toy Car',
    'Toy CAR'
);

foreach($variations as $variation) {
    echo "{$base} and {$variation} = " . similar_text($base, $variation);
}
```

Thus it will match characters in case-sensitive way, you can `strtolower` both strings for better results.

Note that complexity is `O(N**3)` where N is the length of the longest string.

Comment: Oh nice, I vaguely remember an implementation like this but did not know that the php function similar_text existed, thanks! Will try this and will wait a bit to see if there are any more comments and/or answers, just in case.

Comment: I found this to be the best way with strpos helping to make sure that I don't get any weird matches. I also counted the string length so that I don't try to match empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with strpos() as well, you just need to add extra condition how many word you want to check. Logic is something like this,

```
$str = "Toy car";
$splits = split(" ",$str);

if ( strpos($splits[0]) !== false && strpos($splits[1]) !== false ){
  echo "found";
}
```

Comment: I believe this implementation would match similar products like "Toy boat" and "Toy car" which causes issues. However your example code seems to be wrong as strpos() needs two arguments to work?